# How to get the id of the clicked row and using that id display that row's information-Using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a table and every tr has a button inside it. Now when I clicked that button I want to listen to the click event and display that tr's information on the page.
here is the html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <div class="cc-manage"> 
                <a class="button manage-cc">Manage</a>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>expiry</td>
            <div class="cc-manage"> 
                <a class="button manage-cc">Manage</a>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Js:

```
$('.manage-cc').on("click", function() {
  var clicked = $(this).closest('tr'); //getting the tr clicked
   var manageCC = new manageCCModel([],{ id: id });
   manageCC.fetch({
    url: 'fetch/account/list',
    success: function(managecc){
        var manageCCTemplate = Mustache.render(manageCCTmpl, managecc.attributes.data); 
        $("#account").html(manageCCTemplate);
});
```

Above im trying to fetch the information of the tr clicked, however in my case,no matter which 'tr' i click, it always displays the information of the first 'tr'. Also I'm able to listen to the click event above, but I'm not sure where to store that 'id' so that when the click occurs, the event will look for which 'tr' has been clicked and will display that information on the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/tLen4o7L/

Please find below the o/p of my html table:

[image]

Below is the place where, the button clicks and above is the image shown of the info page displayed on the click.....

[image]

here is the source:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <div class="cc-manage">
      <a class="button manage-cc">Manage</a>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Please let me know of needed more details.
Any ideas how to achieve this??
Thanks

Comment: Your sample `tr` element does not have an `id`. Do you mean [row] index?

Comment: Each tr could have id that matches with DB id value example <tr id="DBID1"></tr>

Comment: when you click a row do you get data associated with it from the database

Comment: I think you need to move your `<div>` into it's own `<td>` tag, this is not valid HTML

Comment: @AAB: no i dont get the associated data, coz my guess is, these tr's are dynamically generated so are these buttons, hence cannot add id's to them manually...but i think while fetching the data itself i should be able to store the id of the tr clicked, else it will fetch always the default one, ie first one in this case...

Comment: @PeterKA: yes, something like row[index], but im not sure how to tell the url before fetching the data which tr has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix the html

```
 <table>        
      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Expire Date:</td> 
           <td>10 March 2015</td> 
           <td> 
              <div class="cc-manage">
                    <button class="button manage-cc">Manage</button>

              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Card number:</td> 
           <td>1111222233334444</td> 
           <td> 
              <div class="cc-manage">
                    <button class="button manage-cc">Manage</button>                        
              </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id='account'></div>
```

With this html, you can do something like:

```
 $('.manage-cc').on("click", function() {
      var clickedrow = $(this).closest('tr');
      var descriptionCell = clickedrow.firstChild();
      var valueCell = descriptionCell.next();

      $("#account").html(descriptionCell.text() + " : " + valueCell.text() );
  });
```

Here is a simple demo : https://jsfiddle.net/tLen4o7L/1/

Comment: im unable to add id's manually as the tr's are dynamically generated..how else can i tackle w/o using the tr id's?

Comment: @user1234 what information do you need about `tr`s?

Comment: its a page displaying credit card info, expiry date and expiry month. so now for all clicked tr's it shows the same expiry date/month and the cc info, whereas they all are different..and all these elements inside the table are dynamically generated, so they dont hv id's by default..

Comment: @user1234 can you check my code again? it really depends on how you table looks like. Can you share html output of your table?

Comment: I've added the image above of how the html looks on click of any 'tr'..as of now for every 'tr' clicked shows the same above o/p

Comment: @user1234 can you right-click and choose "view source" in the browser? And I do not  see and button to click in your form?

Comment: above i have added the 2 images, the first one is the result of the clicked tr and the second is where the button clicks...

Comment: @user1234 can you include all table details that also includes `Expire` information? you included the `<tr>` for button, can you provide more `html`

Comment: @user1234 please check this https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/vbL06p9u/2/ and let me know if it works for you ?

Comment: your fiddle works otherwise, but here im trying to store the variables before fetching the info from the db, so that it displays the correct 'tr' data: http://jsfiddle.net/vbL06p9u/3/

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLen4o7L/6/)

Each of the button-containing divs need to be inside a `td` element.

To get the `index` of the row clicked use:

```
var index = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').index(clicked);
```

To get the `id` of the row clicked use:

```
var id = clicked.prop('id');
```

*Bear in mind that your `tr` elements do not have ids.*

Comment: Thanks @PeterKA, i got the id of the tr clicked, but my whole issue revolves, since im using the backbone fetch to grab the data of the 'tr', how can i let know the backbone model, which tr info to display?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know backbone. You may want to indicate that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

in html you can have a data attribute on any tag.  you can use this to associate data with the element like this:

```
<table>     
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td> Date </td>
     <td>
       <div class="cc-manage">
         <a class="button manage-cc" data-rowtype="date">Manage</a>
       </div>
     </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> expiry </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cc-manage">
          <a class="button manage-cc" data-rowtype="expiry">Manage</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

now you can just look at the data of the "this" element in your event and know which row you are on.

some documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes